# Poa question erc token

Tags: contract-development, gas, poa

I want to ask a question in regards to poa Consensus.

If I was looking to fork ethereum and setup my own side ledger using poa and creating/erc specific tokens on this chain..is there a way where I can front the cost of the nodes to handle all the transactions related to those erc tokens?

I know it's such a noob question..I have an idea for a project and I will front the entire cost for the nodes to make sure customers/traders are not hindered by gas fees (I'll put my money where my mouth is)...can I do this and still be within the ethereum ecosystem? If so any one point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you create your own private network (judging by the PoA consensus), then you can put there an arbitrary amount of Ethers to certain accounts and then use them to distribute to user accounts to pay for transactions.
But these Ethers will have nothing to do with the "real" public Ethereum.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm basically looking to develop a token that has no transactional fee for its entire life time (I will pay for and maintain the ledger/nodes needed). However I would "one day" not now and maybe will or will not want to try sell these tokens for some monetary value for a project I have in mind where these tokens will be used.... and i don't want to lumber investors with gas fees from nefarious validators...but then again I would possibly want to list these tokens on a dex... from my research and talking to some blockchain specialists, they saying its not possible.

Comment: Can then use the Quorum for your network? In terms of smart contracts, it is very close to Ethereum, but does not involve transaction fees.

Comment: Yes I looked at quorum, the problem will be how to list on dex in future in need be?

Comment: Would I have to deploy/code my own exchange to retrieve capital from other tokens?